# Numpy concatenation takes too much memory. Is there a more efficient way?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

I have two NumPy arrays, A and B.

> A has shape (1000000, 512) and B has shape (1000000, 4) I am trying to concatenate them to get an array of shape (1000000, 516).

My problem is that `np.concatenate([A, B], axis=1)` takes way too much memory for some reason. Checking my memory usage, A and B take approximately 5GB (together), but when I run the concatenation my ram usage jumps by approximately 16GB.

> Why is this happening?
> Is there a more efficient way of doing this operation for large arrays?

I tried doing the concatenation in batches but it doesn't help much and seems like the memory is not freed between iterations.

Comment: Can you check the dtype of both arrays?

Comment: Both array have dtype '0'

Comment: @mikksu I changed the type to float and it reduced memory consumption drastically and practically solved my problem :)
Thanks, it took so much of my time.